# Yii2 -Make dropdown row in navbar disable/readOnly based on user type

Tags: php, yii2, navbar, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Is there someone who can help me?
I make a dropdown on of my layout tab menu.
this my dropdown.

```
[
      'label' => '(' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
      'items' => [
          ['label' => 'Change Password', 'url' => ['/site/changepassword']],
          ['label' => 'User Setting', 'url' => ['/user']],
          ['label' => 'test', 'url' => ['/leave-record/leave']],
          '<li class="dropdown-header"></li>',
          ['label' => 'Logout', 'url' => ['/site/logout'],
                                'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']],
      ],
    ],
```

I've 3 user type in user model.
1. Master Admin
2. Normal Admin
3. Normal User

if Master Admin login, he can access all rows in dropdown. Then if normal admin login row "User Setting" become disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for an item you can use the  visible attribute  assign  a proper condition

eg:

```
[
      ['label' => 'Change Password', 'url' => ['/site/changepassword']],
      [
         'label' => 'User Setting', 
          'url' => ['/user'],
          'visible' => Yii::$app->User->can('masterAdmin'),
      ],
 ],
```

for two user type you could use a $check

```
$check = ((Yii::$app->User->can('masterAdmin') || Yii::$app->User->can('admin')) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

.

```
 ...
 'label' => 'User Setting', 
  'url' => ['/user'],
 'visible' =>$check,
```

Comment: but how to create 2 user type can access that's row?